# Make the string into the variables name

Tags: string, variables

i want to create a nontransitiv dice game

```
A = [3, 5, 7]
B = [2, 4, 9]
C = [1, 6, 8]

choice1 = input("Chose a Dice (A/B/C)")
result1 = random.choice(choice1)
```

The user will enter a string like "A" and i want it to become the variable A so that the random.choice function will output a random number from the corresponding list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a dictionary with the letters as keys and the arrays as values. Then, whatever the user puts, key into the dictionary.

```
diceDict = {
  "A": [3, 5, 7],
  "B": [2, 4, 9],
  "C": [1, 6, 8]
}

result = random.choice(diceDict[choice1])
```

Comment: in dictionarys you have to use ":" instead of "="

Comment: @WithiWeis you're right! fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language this is written in but you need to perform some sort of check on the user entered value....  e.g

*(pseudocode)*

```
if (choice1 === "A") getRandomFromArray(A) 
if (choice1 === "B") getRandomFromArray(B) 
.... etc...
```